# Read properties and call methods from another object Javascript Prototype Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

Im trying to get how can I access properties from another constructor. I want to separate objects like App, Effects, Utils for example and call properties and methods from one to another. Is that possible, or is this way completely wrong way?

```
var App = function() {

    this.someProperty = 'Lorem';
    this.init();
};

App.prototype = {

    init:function(){
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents:function(){

        var self = this;

        $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.windowWidth = $(window).width();
            // Is that Correct?
            Utils.prototype.resizeElement(this.windowWidth);
        });

    }

};


var Utils = function(){};


Utils.prototype = {

    resizeElement: function(windowW){
        console.log(windowW);   
    },

    someMethod:function(){

        // How can i access property written in App constructor?
        console.log(this.someProperty);
    }

};


var Effects = function(){
    this.init();
};


Effects.prototype = {

    hideElement:function(ele){
        $(ele).hide();
    }

};


var app = new App();
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  I don't see an `init` declaration for `Effects`.  Are you saying you'd want that to call `App.init`?

Comment: For example in object App method bindEvents i want to call method resizeElement that is in object Utils, am I doing it correctly? Or for eg. i want to read property this.someProperty that is defined in App object but i want to read it in Utils object..did you get it?

Comment: Ok I answered.  You are confusing `object` (instance) and `class` here.  Look at my examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have classes, the classes themselves don't serve for much.  *Instances* of classes are what you want.  So calling `Utils.resizeElement` from `App` wouldn't do anything, as `resizeElement` is a part of the prototype (i.e. part of what an *instance* gets, not what the *class* itself gets).

You need to decide if you're grouping methods and concepts into a single-instance, in which case you could just use a JS object, such as:

```
var Utils = {
  resizeElement: function(window) { ... }
}
```

If you had an object called `Utils` that had a method property called `resizeElement` then you could call it from `App` with `Utils.resizeElement`.

If you truly want a class, then you have two choices: 1) pass an *instance* of a `Utils` to your `App` or create a new instance inside `App`.

Option 1:

```
var App = function(utils) {
    this.utils = utils;
    this.someProperty = 'Lorem';
    this.init();
};

App.prototype = {

    init: function(){
        this.bindEvents();
        this.utils.resizeElement(...);
    }
}

var u = new Utils();
var a = new App(u);
```

Or do it internally

```
var App = function() {
    this.utils = new Utils();
    this.someProperty = 'Lorem';
    this.init();
};

App.prototype = {

    init: function(){
        this.bindEvents();
        this.utils.resizeElement(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, working good, thanks!! and can i ask you one more thing, how can i read the property that is defined in App constructor? is that possible or i need to pass as argument to method?

Comment: What property in the app constructor? `this.someProperty = 'Lorem';`?  If so, then you can access it once you've created an instance of `App`, such as: `var a = new App(); alert(a.someProperty);`